# Magento form-action CSP not working

Tags: magento2, csp, content-security-policy

```
Refused to send form data to 'https://example.com/customer/account/logout/'
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 
'self' secure.authorize.net test.authorize.net pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com 
www.paypal.com www.sandbox.paypal.com *.facebook.com ".
```

I really don't understand that I have added 'https://example.com/' into csp_whitelist by form-action. But it still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself. Post it here if anyone needs in future:

When user click logout button, we will send a form to  [https://example.com/customer/account/logout/'](https://example.com/customer/account/logout/%27). Due to the same domain, that is why error mentioned it is form-action 'self'.

But after it, the page redirects to another url, which is not visible in the CSP report.

> The reason why the target url of the redirect is not visible in the
> CSP report (which is really confusing) is a security issue, see
> https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#create-violation-for-request, it
> would otherwise be possible to analyse the behaviour of form
> endpoints.

The solution: I added the redirect endpoint url into 'form-action' CSP.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try once with wildcard in form-action

[image]

Comment: I tried, it does not work.